# Calculate the area of the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ lying in the region of space defined by $x \leq 0 \space, y \leq 0 \space, 0 \leq z \leq 1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The formula that I have been using for finding area is of a surface is :

$A = \iint dS = \iint \sqrt{1 + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})^2 } \space dxdy$

So I tried to set this problem as so :

$A = \iiint dS = \iiint \sqrt{1 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})^2 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})^2  } \space dxdydz$

In this question setting the bounds and finding the partial derivatives lead me to this :

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{z} \int_{-\sqrt{z^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{z^2-y^2}} \sqrt{1 + 4x^2 + 4y^2 + 4z^2} dxdydz$

This gives an answer in wolfram alpha that is equivalent to the answer in the text but the text gives this formula for finding the surface area involving three variables :

$A = \iint dS = \iint \sqrt{1 + (\frac{\partial (y,z)}{\partial (u,v)})^2 + (\frac{\partial (x,z)}{\partial (u,v)})^2 + (\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)})^2} \space dudv$

Why is it neccesary to paramatize the surface by u and v then take the cross product of each ?

Comment: The triple integral, I cannot interpret it as anything useful for the problem. It is a integral over the volume of the conical frustum, between $z=0$ and $z=1$, of something similar to the module of the gradient. The area actually is calculated parametrizing the surface (two variables) and as element of area vectors perpendiculars to the surface (cross product of vectors tangent to the surface obtained from the partial derivatives...)

Comment: Sorry, is that meant t be $x,y \geq 0$ ?

Comment: Also, have you considered using Cylindrical co-ordinates over Cartesian?

Comment: To add to Rafa's comment above, you should use your original formula (not the one with three variables).  The integral should be $\iint \sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)} \, dx \, dy$, where the domain of integration is one quarter of the unit circle.